# How to get text in span tag with beautifulsoup and python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup with html5lib to try to get the number after `QTY:` and I have tried many unsuccessful methods.

This is the span tag format:

```
  <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch_ctl45_lblPr">0080970139<br>QTY: 255</span>
```

This is the code that produces the span tag:

```
  PreQty = container1.find(id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch_ctl03_lblPr")
```

I have tried adding .text, .get_text() and others but they don't work

How could I get the value after `QTY:`?

I just need the next step to get the text out of the span tag

```
     <span id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch_ctl45_lblPr">0080970139<br>QTY: 255</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.select()` [returns a list of matching elements](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors). So if your selector matches any elements, you will first need to retrieve the element from the array, and then you can access it's `.text` attribute.

To demonstrate, you could do something like:

```
for element in PreQty:
    print(element.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, the tricky part here is to find the "QTY" after the `<br>` tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """<span id="ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch_ctl45_lblPr">0080970139<br>QTY: 255</span>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(text,'html.parser')
QTY = soup.find("span", id = "ctl00_cph1_grdRfqSearch_ctl45_lblPr" ).find('br').next_sibling
print(QTY)

#outputs 
QTY: 255
```

Comment: my code is parsed in html5lib. How would it look with html5lib?

Comment: @e.iluf you can use the html5 parser by using "html5"